# replace value of JSON field using SPEL in SpringXD

Tags: json, spring-xd, spring-el, jsonpath

I get json in stream and try to replace value of one field in payload.
`transform --expression=payload.replaceAll()` does not fit my needs as it treat payload as String.
I think of such operation

```
transform --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.result.grupy[*].lp')='new_value'
```

but it does not perform this assigment. How construct SPEL/JsonPath expression to set new value?

I need something like payload.setField('lp','new_value')

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that; you would need a custom processor module, or a custom SpEL function, to make changes like that.

The `#jsonPath` function simply returns an element from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `payload.replace()` expression doesn't fit your requirements, but the `#jsonPath()` SpEL-fuction is for `extraction` the data from JSON, not for modification.

From other side you misunderstood a bit a concept of `transformer` component. It returns a new object, but doesn't modify the request.

To achieve your requirements you should take a look to the [Content Enricher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher), which exactly is intended to modify the incoming `payload` and return it as a reply.

To simplify your life you should take a look to the `<int:object-to-map-transformer>` to have ability to change field from the next `<int:enricher>` component.

Right, for this purpose you should write your own `processor` module.